# Where moodle store scorm grades?

Tags: moodle, scorm

I'm developing a web application to report moodle information. One of the report show scorm grades, and in analysis time, I concluded that information about scorm grades were stored in scorm_scoes_track table of the database.

But something is wrong... When in moodle administrator area if I go to Course administration > Grades and select the scorm I can see the grades showing in my application report (that's correct), but also other many grades that don't exists in scorm_scoes_track table!

So I think there has to be another place where this grades are being stored.

Do you know? any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Main tables for definitive grades are grade_grades and grade_grades_history.

Make sure your cron is running to populate those tables frequently.

scorm_scoes_track seems to be a tracking table to keep log of user interactions with SCORM objects.

For details on how Moodle grades and SCORM objects work see [here](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/SCORM_FAQ#SCORM_and_the_Gradebook).